# Json.Net expand JToken fields base on convention

Tags: c#, json, recursion, json.net

I have the following json structure:

```json
{
    "access:hasPermission": true,
    "access:permission:assemble_document": true,
    "access:permission:can:modify": true,
    "access:permission:can:print": true,
    "access:permission:can:print_degraded": true,
    "access:permission:extract_content": true,
    "access:permission:modify_annotations": true,
    "doc:creator": "me",
    "doc:description": "sample description",
    "ping":"pong"
}
```

and all I want is to process that json recursively such that end result become like this:

```json
{
    "access":{
       "hasPermission":true,
       "permission":{
         "assemble_document": true,
         "can":{
             "modify": true,
             "print": true,
             "print_degraded": true,
         },
         "extract_content": true,
         "modify_annotations": true,
        }
     },
     "doc":{
       "creator": "me",
       "description": "sample description",
     },

    "ping":"pong"
}
```

I am using C# with Newtonsoft.Json

```cs
public static JObject Expand(this JObject jToken,char separator=':')
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Fine, and where is your attempt to solve a problem? Deleted answer isn't available for most users, except you and 10k rep guys

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  my first method did not behave well on arrays , so i had to delete it permanently till fixing, now posted updated version

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved my problem with the code below :
and this method goes well also in json array

```cs
public static JToken Expand(this JToken jToken, string separators = ":.")
        {
            if (jToken is JValue jValue) return jValue;

            JToken Empty() => JToken.Parse("{}");

            jToken = JToken.Parse(jToken.ToString());
            switch (jToken)
            {
                case JObject jObj:
                {
                    var js = Empty();
                    foreach (var jProp in jObj.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().ToArray())
                    {
                        if (jProp.Path.Contains("[")) continue;
                        var path = jProp.Path.Split(separators.ToCharArray());
                        var tmp = js;
                        foreach (var s in path)
                        {
                            if (tmp[s] == null)
                            {
                                tmp[s] = Empty();
                            }

                            tmp = tmp[s];
                        }

                        if (tmp.Parent is JProperty jParentProp)
                        {
                            if (jProp.Value is JValue)
                            {
                                jParentProp.Value = jProp.Value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var x = JToken.Parse(jProp.Value.ToString()).Expand(separators);
                                jParentProp.Value = x;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //nothing to do here
                            ;
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var jArr in jObj.Descendants().OfType<JArray>().ToArray())
                    {
                        foreach (var jItem in jArr.ToArray())
                        {
                            jItem.Replace(jItem.Expand(separators));
                        }
                    }

                    return js;
                }
                case JArray jArray:
                {
                    foreach (var jItem in jArray.ToArray())
                    {
                        jItem.Replace(jItem.Expand(separators));
                    }

                    return jArray;
                }
                default:
                    return jToken;
            }
        }
```